# Best approach to getting results out of goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I have two functions that I cannot change (see `first()` and `second()` below). They are returning some data and errors (the output data is different, but in the examples below I use `(string, error)` for simplicity)

I would like to run them in separate goroutines - my approach:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func first(name string) (string, error) {
    if name == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("empty name is not allowed")
    }
    fmt.Println("processing first")
    return fmt.Sprintf("First hello %s", name), nil
}

func second(name string) (string, error) {
    if name == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("empty name is not allowed")
    }
    fmt.Println("processing second")
    return fmt.Sprintf("Second hello %s", name), nil
}

func main() {
    firstCh := make(chan string)
    secondCh := make(chan string)
    
    go func() {
        defer close(firstCh)
        res, err := first("one")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to run first: %v\n", err)
        }
        firstCh <- res
    }()

    go func() {
        defer close(secondCh)
        res, err := second("two")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to run second: %v\n", err)
        }
        secondCh <- res
    }()

    resultsOne := <-firstCh
    resultsTwo := <-secondCh

    // It's important for my app to do error checking and stop if errors exist.
    if resultsOne == "" || resultsTwo == "" {
        fmt.Println("There was an ERROR")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("ONE:", resultsOne)
    fmt.Println("TWO:", resultsTwo)
}
```

I believe one caveat is that `resultsOne := <- firstCh` blocks until first goroutine finishes, *but I don't care too much about this*.

Can you please confirm that my approach is good? What other approaches would be better in my situation?

Comment: Looks good. I would recommend to improve a bit: 1) introduce a type `type res struct { s string; err error}` and send values of this type from the goroutines; the receiver is oblidged to first inspect the `err` field, then `s`, iff the former is `nil`; 2) if the identity of the result is not important (which is "first" and which is "second") you could just send them over a single channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot use a `type res struct` because the `s` (the data returned by the two functions) is *not* identical).  As for your 2nd suggestion, unfortunately identity *matters* in my app.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the fact the data returned is not identical? @user8285681 ?

Comment: I said from the beginning that the data is not the same, but I used `(string, error)` as return for both functions, for simplicity reasons!

Comment: Well, then define `firstResult` and `secondResult`, what's the problem? :) I wanted to highlight that printing a log line in case of an error most of the time is the worst way to handle an error. Errors should be conveyed to whoever processes the result, and using a `struct` type for that is the usual approach for such a case in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example looks mostly good. A couple improvements are:

- declaring your channels as buffered

```
   firstCh := make(chan string, 1)
   secondCh := make(chan string, 1)
```

With unbuffered channels, send operations block (until someone receives). If your goroutine #2 is much faster than the first, it will have to wait until the first finishes as well, since you receive in sequence:

```
    resultsOne := <-firstCh // waiting on this one first
    resultsTwo := <-secondCh // sender blocked because the main thread hasn't reached this point
```

- use `"golang.org/x/sync/errgroup".Group`. The program will feel "less native" but it dispenses you from managing channels by hand — which trades, in a non-contrived setting, for sync'ing writes on the results:

```
func main() {
    var (
        resultsOne string
        resultsTwo string
    )

    g := errgroup.Group{}
    
    g.Go(func() error {
        res, err := first("one")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        resultsOne = res
        return nil
    })

    g.Go(func() error {
        res, err := second("two")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        resultsTwo = res
        return nil
    })

    err := g.Wait()
    // ... handle err
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, using buffered channels allows both `first()` and `second()` functions to finish independently, but in the grand scheme of things, the following still is true: `resultsOne := <-firstCh` blocks the entire program until `first()` has finished.